# Javascript undefined innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I have googled a lot and there seems to be a lot of talk regarding jQuery and the problem I'm having, however I'm using purely JavaScript.

I am just having a problem with not being able to validate the input because it is undefined.

**If my HTML is needed I will post, but i think this can be solved without it.

```
function fnValidation()
    {
        var validator = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/; //regex
        var input = document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML; 

        if (!(input.match(validator)))
        {
            alert("Please enter only alphabetical characters!");
        }
        printReceipt();
    }
```

I dug this old code up from a pervious problem and decided to salvage the username validation but am now having the problem described above

Comment: inputs don't have innerHTML. They have value

Comment: ohhh! is it just my variable name being a keywork in javascript?

Comment: try `document.getElementById("fn").value` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Input element doesn't have innerHTML, because all it has its value inside value attribute on html & value property
Inside DOM.

You should use

```
document.getElementById("fn").value
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I was under the impression .innerHTML would return the HTML inside the element

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks for heads up..I editted that code from mobile which accendently made starting letter in caps..

Answer (score 0):

should be var input = document.getElementById("fn").value   and not innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

.innerHTML will return the string inside that id tag example here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hazetekllc/1ddfcpkz/)

`<h1 id="fn">Hello World!</h1>`
the id is 'fn' the innerHTML is Hello Wold!